# How to legend a raster using directly the raster attribute table and displaying the legend only for class displayed in the raster?

Tags: r, dictionary, legend, raster, categorical-data

I would like to use  the raster attribute table information to create the legend of a raster such as the raster [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgC2P.png) and display the legend only for the class displayed in the raster. I build an example to explain what I would like to get.

**1/ Build the raster**

```
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <-sample(1:3,ncell(r),replace=T)
```

**2/ Add the Raster Attribute Table**

```
r <- ratify(r) # build the Raster Attibute table
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]#get the values of the unique cell frot the attribute table
rat$legend <- c('Class A', 'Class B', 'Class C')
levels(r) <- rat
```

**3/ Plot the raster** Fig [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgC2P.png)

```
my_col=c('blue','red','green')
plot(r,col=my_col,legend=F,box=F,axes=F)
legend(x='top', legend =rat$legend,fill = my_col)
```

I would like to replace the `legend =rat$legend` parammeter by a properties of the raster linked to the ratser attribute table. I have tried different combination using `levels()` such as `c(levels(r)[[1]][1])` but I generate a list and not a character not usable in the legend parameter.

**4/ Crop and plot the raster to a part with only 2 classes (here the 4 pixels at the down right extent)** Fig [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzF8M.png)

```
rcrop<-crop(r,extent(r,9,10,9,10))
plot(rcrop,col=my_col,legend=F,box=F,axes=F)
```

For this second fig, I thus would like to diplay automatically only the legend of the class displayed on the raster [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzF8M.png).

[image: Raster with legend]

[image: Cropped raster with legend]

---

Here is the solution proposed by Roman [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAJdN.png). 
[image: Solution proposed by Roman]

Comment: Roman's answer is good; just wanted to point out that if you have a `list` and want a character vector, you can always do `as.character(unlist(mylist))`

Comment: @Carl : Thanks, indeed when I use 'legend(x='top', legend =as.character(unlist( c(levels(r)[[1]][2]))),fill = my_col)' , I directly get the legend from the attribute raster table. Anyway, the Roman's answer does not solve the problem as it create a new legend not based on the raster attribute table. I'm thus losing the 'Class A',... legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use `lattice` graphics, the `levelplot` method
defined in the `rasterVis`
[package](http://oscarperpinan.github.com/rastervis/) is able to
display categorical data with a legend based on the RAT:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- rep(1:4, each=25)

r <- ratify(r) 
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$legend <- c('Class A', 'Class B', 'Class C', 'Class D')
levels(r) <- rat

levelplot(r)
```

[image: rat.png]

Besides, I have
[commited some changes](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/commit/06e51ef80b8efc0b9f7e52273f60f5b3b9da7f84)
in the
[development version available at GitHub](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/)
to manage a `Raster*` whose RAT levels are not all present in the
data:

```
rcrop <- crop(r,extent(r,6,10,1,10))
levelplot(rcrop)
```

[image: rat crop]

```
rcrop <- crop(r,extent(r,1,5,1,10))
levelplot(rcrop)
```

[image: rat crop2]

Comment: @ Oscar:Thanks for your answer and the changes to ratserVis. I think it could be interesting to link the rat to a color as it is usefull to plot the same color for the same value. I thus add a column color in the rat.

Comment: @Wraf: I agree, is is better to keep colors for each class. A manual solution is to define `col.regions` or `par.settings` in each `levelplot` call. It would be better to use the content of the `legend` slot of the `RasterLayer` object, but it is not implemented in `levelplot` yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe query the `rcrop` raster to find out which are the levels in the cropped raster and pass that to the legend?

```
legend(x = 'top', legend = unique(getValues(rcrop)), fill = my_col)
```

Comment: @ Roman : Using your proposition allows to have a legend with only 2 classes but doesn't allow to use the Raster Attribute Table giving not the graph expected. I add the result I got with what you proposed in my question.

Comment: Try x<-data.frame(levels(rcrop)),
x[unique(getValues(rcrop)),2]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Based on what you proposed I found a solution:

```
plot(rcrop,col=my_col[unique(getValues(rcrop))],legend=F,box=F,axes=F)
legend_full<-data.frame(levels(rcrop))
legend(x='top', legend =as.character(unlist(legend_full[unique(getValues(rcrop)),2])),fill = my_col[unique(getValues(rcrop))])
```

It works and allows to be independent of the values displayed in the raster.