# plot raster with discrete colors using rasterVis

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, rastervis

I have a few rasters I would like to plot using gplot in the rasterVis package. I just discovered gplot (which is fantastic and so much faster than doing data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))). However, I can't get a discrete image to show. Normally if r is a raster, I'd do:

```
rdf=data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
rdf$cuts=cut(rdf$value,breaks=seq(0,max(rdf$value),length.out=5))
ggplot(rdf)+geom_raster(aes(x,y,fill=cuts))
```

But is there a way to avoid the call to rasterToPoints? It is very slow with large rasters. I did find I could do:

```
cuts=cut_interval(r@data@values,n=5)
```

but if you set the fill to cuts it plots the integer representation of the factors.

Here is some reproducible data:

```
x=seq(-107,-106,.1)
y=seq(33,34,.1)
coords=expand.grid(x,y)
rdf=data.frame(coords,depth=runif(nrow(coords),0,2)))
names(rdf)=c('x','y','value')
r=rasterFromXYZ(rdf)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gplot` is a very simple wrapper around `ggplot` so don't expect too
much from it. Instead, you can use part of its code to build your own
solution. The main point here is to use `sampleRegular` to reduce the
number of points to be displayed.

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

x <- sampleRegular(r, size=5000, asRaster = TRUE)
dat <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
dat$cuts <- cut(dat$value,
    breaks=seq(0, max(dat$value), length.out=5))
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = dat) +
    geom_raster(aes(x, y, fill=cuts))
```

However, if you are open to plot without `ggplot2` you may find useful
this other
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586945/how-to-legend-a-raster-using-directly-the-raster-attribute-table-and-displaying/19610442#19610442).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. sampleRegular looks promising, didn't know about that.I'm also not bound to ggplot2 although my familiarity with it makes it attractive.