# contour map of spatial-temporal K function

Tags: r, matlab

I have latitude and longitude point data over time. I would like to plot (in R or Matlab) a contour map of spatial-temporal K function (much like the one below), but have no idea how. Any suggestions would be great![image]

Comment: The paper doesn't go into details of how to calculate the spatial-temporal K function? No supplementary material?

Comment: Link to paper if anyone cares: http://www.plosone.org/article/metrics/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0013575

Comment: @Roman - no, not that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to compute space-time K-functions using the `stkhat` function in the `splancs` package. I make some random data on a space-time cube, then compute the soace-time K function estimate for a spatial range up to 0.3 distance units and 0.3 time units.

```
> require(splancs)
> xyt=matrix(runif(3000),ncol=3)
> poly=bboxx(spoints(c(0,1,0,1)))
> tlim=c(0,1)
> s=seq(0,.3,len=51)[-1]
> t=s
> stk = stkhat(xyt[,1:2], xyt[,3], poly, tlim, s,t)
> image(str$kst)
> require(lattice)
> image(x=stk$s, y=stk$t,z = stk$kst)
```

Comment: Thanks Spacedman! I'm just a little confused as to how to set up my data frame for this code (I'm not an experienced R user). I have a data matrix of 110 columns consisting of: latitude and longitude coordinates, and corresponding monthly data over 9 years. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also, I have 178 different lat/lon points over 108 months. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This isn't really the place to make you a better R user - practice a bit more, maybe read the R Spatial Task View and come back if you have more specific programming questions. Notice how this question has been downvoted? Read more R questions here to see what makes a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an outline of how you might start this in `R`. Note that this does not address the question of 'how to compute a spatial-temporal K function'.

First, get example data from [plot raster with discrete colors using rasterVis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20256538/1036500)

```
x=seq(-107,-106,.1)
y=seq(33,34,.1)
coords=expand.grid(x,y)
data1=data.frame(coords,depth=runif(nrow(coords),0,2))
names(data1)=c('x','y','value')

# get max and min values 
xmn=min(data1[,1]); xmx=max(data1[,1])
ymn=min(data1[,2]); ymx=max(data1[,2])
```

Now compute an interpolated raster from the raw data...

```
# compute interpolated raster. Note that this is not the 'spatial-temporal K function' requested in the question, as pointed out in a comment below, but a linear interpolation
library(akima)
akima.li <- interp(data1[,1], data1[,2], data1[,3], duplicate = "median",
                   xo=seq(xmn,xmx, length=100),
                   yo=seq(ymn,ymx, length=100))
```

Plot the raster...

```
# plot interpolated raster 
image(akima.li, col = rainbow(100, alpha = 1))
```

[image]

Plot the raster as a contour plot...

```
# plot interpolated contour 
contour(akima.li, nlevels = 3)
```

[image]

Now put the raster and contour together and this is close to the example image you posted...

```
# put the raster and contours together
image(akima.li, col = rainbow(100, alpha = 1))
contour(akima.li, nlevels = 3, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

And with a few minor tweaks, here is a very close match to the style of the example...

```
image(akima.li, col = gray.colors(10, start = 0, end = 0.9, gamma = 2.2, alpha = 1))
contour(akima.li, nlevels = 3, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Finally, this is pretty much a match, with grey-scale contour fill, contour labels but no contour lines

```
image(akima.li, col = gray.colors(10, start = 0, end = 1, gamma = 1, alpha = 1))
contour(akima.li, nlevels = 3, add = TRUE, lty = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: You've not answered half the question - how to compute the spatial-temporal K-function. You've just shown how to plot coloured matrices, which is probably a dupe of another question. Is this really all the questioner wanted?

Comment: The questioner has accepted this so it would be more appropriate to edit the question and to remove the reference to space-time k-functions and make it a question on how to plot rasters. Then your answer is perfect. If the questioner cared about computing space-time K functions they wouldn't have accepted this answer.

Comment: Sorry - didn't actually mean to accept this answer - it was just generally helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I stumbled across your question, because I am myself dealing with this kind of analysis now. I don't know if you still need an answer, but one way of computing it is to use stpp package in R.

The function is named STIKhat and you can plot it using plotK.

The documentation is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stpp/stpp.pdf).     Its very easy to follow that's why I dont put it here. Hope it helps someone that might have the same question!