# understanding inputs for stkhat in the splancs package

Tags: r

I have latitude and longitude point data (50 points) over time (80 months).

I want to use stkhat in the splancs package to plot space-time K-functions. 
I'm having trouble understanding all of the inputs I need for:

```
stkhat(pts, times, poly, tlimits, s, tm)
```

This is my understanding, which is most likely wrong...

`pts` = a matrix of my point data, i.e. 50 columns, 80 rows?

`times` = a vector of times, i.e 1 to 80 months?

`poly` = polygon(longitude,latitide)?

`tlimits` = c(1,80)?

`s` = a vector of spatial distances (not sure how to calculate, possibly `spDistsN1(coordinates(longitude), coordinates(latitude))`?)

`tm` = a vector of times for the analysis (`times` again?!)

Comment: Recent example of usage here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20263868/1036500